# How to make a class hide based on some attribute value used within the class

Tags: jquery

How to get the xyztype from the class and based on the attr xyztype how to hide the class??

I used

```
$(textforhtml).find('input[fictype=FICPicklist]').parent().addClass("hide");
console.log($(textforhtml));
console.log(textforhtml);
```

But the addclass("hide") is not added

code:

```
<div class="large-6 columns">
<input type="hidden" id="hdnMandFd10" value="false">
<div class="row collapse">
<div class="small-5 columns">
<label xyzlabel="" class="inline CatalogueFont" id="dragField10" value="xyzUW.clientcode.label" onclick="showFieldProperties('10','PARTY',1)">xyzUW.clientcode.label</label>
</div>

<div class="small-2 columns"><input id="valuefd10" value="" xyztype="xyzPicklist" pickdetails="PARTY:" onclick="showFieldProperties('10','PARTY',2)" class="round ui-autocomplete-input" type="text" maxlength="8" autocomplete="off" name="policy[IUWP1_CLI_CD]" style="padding-right:0px;"></div><div class="small-5 columns"><input id="valueDescFd10" style="padding-left:0px;" xyztype="xyzPicklist" pickdetails="PARTY:" pickdescdetails="" class="round ui-autocomplete-input" type="text" value="" placeholder="Description" autocomplete="off" name="policy[IUWP1_CLI_CD_DESC]"></div><div class="small-1 pull-1 radius columns"></div>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code has no element which matches your `input[fictype=FICPicklist]` selector. On top of that, `fictype`, `pickdetails`, `pickdescdetails`, `xyztype` and `xyzlabel` aren't valid HTML attributes, so this would fail HTML validation.

Comment: use valid selector's and it will add the class ...

Comment: @JamesDonnelly - But if you would want your own custom attribute you'd have to prepend it with `data-`, like `data-xyzlabel`.

Answer (score 0):

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LmDAc/3/

Use

```
$("*[xyztype='xyzPicklist']").addClass("hide");
```

Comment: `each()` is redundant here. `$("*[xyztype]").addClass("hide)` would do exactly the same thing.

Comment: If i have xyztype="xyzPicklist" ,xyztype="xyzdate", xyztype="xyztime" etc from this i want to select a particular type like  xyztype="xyzPicklist" and then hide the class

Comment: Indeed you are correct James Donnelly, thx didn't think of that.

I have updated the JSFiddle for your requirements